# Why this does not add the recursive values?

Tags: python

I learned I can fix this problem making c global. But I still do not understand why c does not add the values when the fuction is called from inside the function.

```
def a(b,c):
    for n in b: 
        #print n
        c += str(n)
        #c += "\n"  
        if type(n)is tuple:
            a(n,c)
    return c

b=((1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9))
print a(b,c)
```

It returns `(1, 2, 3)(4, 5, 6)(7, 8, 9)`

and I want `(1, 2, 3)123(4, 5, 6)456(7, 8, 9)789`

Comment: Your recursion condition is never satisfied since when you iterate over b ..every element ..i.e. n is an integer and "if type(n) is tuple" is False. Also if you correct that error you need a stopping condition for recursion. I will suggest you set up your problem with more thoughts about how to start a recursion and how to come out/terminate once it has started.... and yes in just a few months from now sun will set for Python2 as @cricket_007 has already said. All the best

Comment: @Amit Few months? https://pythonclock.org/

Comment: Thank you guys! Don't know if it is the right way to do this but I actually just fixed it by changing line 6 to c = a(b,c). Hard to set my mind to this and follow the code, because before I posted the question I had c += a(b,c) which made all the sense in the world to me but was not working either.

Comment: @cricket_007 ..yes for some reasons I thought it is April 1, 2020 but it is January 1, 2020. The sun has already set for Python 2. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the other logic is correct, you're discarding the recursive return results

You can fix that with `c = a(n,c)`

Comment: Sorry, I thought comments and anwers were the same - they show different in my browser somehow - maybe they are the same...:s  Like I commented earlier c+=a(b,c) was what I had at the beginning and was not giving a good result either. I got around following the code and found that c=a(b,c) is the fix I needed. Thanks!!

Comment: Welcome. You may want to take some time to learn how to use the Python debugger

Comment: I am using it in Houdini. I am yet to find a way to use it and learn outside this program. Any recommendations?

Comment: Personally, I use PyCharm. Never heard of Houdini